# Sample scenes stuck on the "HOLD TIGHT" loading screen - Zenfone AR

Tags: google-project-tango

Tango Unity SDK - Unity 5.6.2 -  Zenfone AR

Trying to run the sample scenes. Scenes getting stuck on the "HOLD TIGHT" loading screen. Tried to find a solution with no luck. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more detail for anyone to help you here.  Error messages, code samples, etc.  Take a look at this article to help you edit the Question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Post this as an Answer then, not just a Comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Updating the Tango Core through Google Play solved the issue.